# cmd.exe renamed - what to do

Tags: windows-10, command-line

A friend's girlfriend ran a hack on my computer, involving booting a Linux from a usb and somehow renaming my system's cmd.exe to sethc.exe to access it from login screen. I can use cmd by running sethc.exe but trying to use pip throws a weird error ("DNS server not authoritative for zone" for command "pip /?") which is probably because of it.

Is there an easy fix? System won't let me rename cmd or sethc normally of course. I'd prefer to fix them myself and not let her touch my computer again, she isn't the most careful person and I don't want her to do anything irreversible...

I've got 64 bit windows 10 home ed, that should be everything useful?
I've got an Ubuntu on a USB too, if that's needed (not sure if it's really that easy though...)

Comment: Try to run `sfc /scannow` "as administrator". It will look and fix possibly "something else" she did

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to rename it from the Ubuntu! I though there would be problems with the file systems, since Windows can't read Linux files but it was really straightforward, just renamed as follows:

```
cmd.exe -> sethc2.exe
sethc.exe -> cmd.exe
sethc2.exe -> sethc.exe
```

So for those who have a similar problem:
1: Download some light linux distro, in my case Ubuntu
2: Make a bootable USB drive and - in my case - when booting, choose "try without installing".
3: Go into your windows folder and perform above steps.